# Forward request to a jspx through servlet

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, jsf-1.2

I have just started a new JSF1.2 project. Though its JSF2.x latest now which has a way better improved features, I ended up starting JSF1.2 for some other reason.

In my application I am trying to redirect to some other view(.jspx file) from the default index.jspx file.

I have tried to do this, through the startup servlet which would redirect to the page I need.

```
<servlet>
    <description>A first jsf app</description>
    <display-name>Moderator</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Moderator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.srk.servlets.Moderator</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Moderator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my servlet I am trying to redirect to the jspx file in this way

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsf/thisapp/starter.jspx").forward(request, response);
}
```

The above code does redirection from servlet. In the above code snippet **thisapp** is my application folder which is parallel to web-inf.

I have moved **thisapp** folder into web-inf and I tried to do redirection from servlet, but it has resulted in 404 error.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/thisapp/starter.jspx").forward(request, response);
```

**More info :**
My web.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Jsf start up application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jspx</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jsf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How can I forward request to files inside web-inf through the servlet in this case.

Comment: No need to move pages to WEB-INF, this is plase for classes. You should redirect to **/thisapp/...**, not to **/jsf/...** if I understad well you.

Comment: @ThrashBean: To protect my pages, I moved folder to WEB-INF.

Comment: To protect? Sorry, I dont understand. But I still think WEB-INF is not place for classes.